# ListView SelectedItem does not work on android xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with the selected item in xamarin forms.
The selected item works on all projects, except on android.

That's when I click on list items that do not work

I've debugged and noticed that the function is not being called, but only in android does this happen, does it have a bug? Or was it even my mistake?

Thanks for listening

PS. Sorry for my English

**SelectedItem method**

```
linha = (Linhas)e.SelectedItem;
        foreach (Linhas item in objBList)
        {

            item.selected = (item == linha);


        }

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            lstView.ItemsSource = null;
            lstView.ItemsSource = objBList;
        });
        ListView lista_linhas = (ListView)sender;
          var  linha_vat_converted = linha.Vat / 100;
        p_name_e.Text = linha.Name_product;
        p_code_e.Text = linha.Ref;
        p_price_e.Text = linha.Pu.ToString("0.00#");
        p_famaly_e.Text = linha.famaly_ref;
        p_qtt_e.Text = linha.qtt.ToString("0.000#");
        p_iva_e.Text = linha_vat_converted.ToString("P");
        p_Unidade_e.Text = linha.Un;
```

*this method is for me to go get the data of the item clicked, and pass it to the other side*

**Xaml of ListView**

```
  <ListView  x:Name="lstView"   RowHeight="50" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected_1"  SeparatorVisibility="None" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="White" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid  Padding="5,10,5,5"  >
                                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="testedalista"
                             NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
                                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="10" />


                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />  
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />

                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"  IsVisible="{Binding selected}"  BackgroundColor="#2379fb"  Grid.Row="0"/>
                                        <Label Grid.RowSpan="2" FontFamily="{StaticResource Open_Sans_Regular}"  Margin="1,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalTextAlignment="Start"  TextColor="#808080"  Font="14" x:Name="linha_desc" Text ="{Binding Name_product}" Style ="{StaticResource SmallName}" />
                                        <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource Open_Sans_Regular}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="#808080"  Font="14" Grid.Column="2" Text = "{Binding qtt , StringFormat=  '{0:0.000#}'}" Style ="{StaticResource SmallName}"  />
                                        <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource Open_Sans_Regular}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="#808080"  Font="14" Grid.Column="3" Text = "{Binding Un}" Style ="{StaticResource SmallName}"  />
                                        <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource Open_Sans_Regular}" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#808080"  Grid.Row="0" Font="14" Grid.Column="4" x:Name="totais_linhas" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text = "{Binding price, StringFormat=  '{0:C2}' }"   />
                                        <Label x:Name="desconto_linha" FontFamily="{StaticResource Open_Sans_Regular}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="#808080"  Font="10" Grid.Column="2" IsVisible="{Binding Selected}" Text = "{Binding Desconto, StringFormat='{0:P}' }" Style ="{StaticResource SmallName}"  />
                                        <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource Open_Sans_Regular}" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  VerticalTextAlignment="End"  TextColor="#808080"  Grid.Row="1" Font="10" Grid.Column="4" x:Name="totais"  Text = "{Binding Pu, StringFormat=  '{0:C2}' }" />

                                    </Grid>
                                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnMore"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                         Text="Adicionar" />
                                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                            Text="Apagar" IsDestructive="True" />
                                        <MenuItem  Clicked="OnQtd" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                            Text="Apagar"  IsDestructive="True" />
                                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: I think the tapgesture and selected item don't get along very well

Comment: Yhea I now! but I can put 2 touches to trigger the selecteditem method??

Comment: You have a TapGestureRecognizer and a SelectedItem method. Which one you intend to call? Or which one is not working? And only in Android? in iOS everything works well?

Comment: TapGestureRecognizer, is only to use 2 touches,  and yes works well on ios